# Reusing Standard Objects in a Managed Package

Tags: force.com, managed-package, appexchange, design

Could any one highlight on effects and implications of using standard objects wherever required in a Managed package. It could be as simple as 'test class failure' resulting into installation failure due to an already existing validation rule on a Standard object in the org in which a customer is trying to install a Managed package.
It would also be great to know if there is any specific strategy one can follow in the design or the code-base so that such situations would be avoided or any other consideration that can be helpful.

We are designing an Appexchange ISVforce App and this is a very crucial decision that we have to make while designing, whether to consider some of the standard Objects like Products and Price Books or to custom build them for our app. Custom building such Objects would definitely be a challenge as there might be a lot of data duplication if some of our potential customers are already using the Standard functionalities related to these standard objects and eventually we have to think on some Integration strategy as well to have a sync between data for the standard and custom objects on a case to case basis which would be an overhead for sure.

Really looking forward for some detailed insights into it as I am unable to get any info on this in any of the docs or anywhere in the community.

Apologies if I am unable to maintain the brevity in my query.

Comment: As you mentioned validation rules could be sometimes a problem, but other things that you have to worry about are record types as well as Person Accounts if you are touching Contacts and Accounts. In any case, your business logic in the app should be as dynamic as possible and take in account all of these sorts of potential issues. I know that this wouldn't answer all of your sub-questions but take it as a tip.